# A formal theory of strength

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\cal K$ be a 2-category with products, and $A$ a pseudomonoid in $\cal K$: this means that there are multiplication and unit 1-cells $\otimes : A \times A \to A$ and $e : 1 \to A$ such that associativity and unit hold.

One says that a *endocell with strength* is a endo-1-cell $t :A \to A$ of $\cal K$, endowed with a 2-cell $\tau : \otimes\circ (1\times t) \Rightarrow t\circ\otimes $
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A \times A @>1\times t>> A\times A \\
@V\otimes VV \tau @VV\otimes V \\ 
A @>>t> A
\end{CD}
$$ such that the equalities between diagrams of 2-cells
$$
\begin{CD}
A \times 1@>1\times e>> A\times A @>>> A\times A\\
@|@VVV\tau @VVV \\
A\times 1 @>>\sim>A@>>>A
\end{CD} =\quad
\begin{CD}
A @>e\times t>> A\times A \\ 
@VtVV  @VV\otimes V\\
A @= A
\end{CD}
$$
$$
\begin{CD}
A\times A\times A @>>> A\times A \\
@VVV \alpha @VVV \\
A\times A @>>> A\\
@VVV\tau @VVV\\
A\times A @>>> A
\end{CD}
=\quad
\begin{CD}
A\times A\times A @>>> A\times A\times A @>>> A\times A \\
@VVV 1\times t @VVV \alpha @VVV\\
A\times A @>>> A\times A @>>> A \\
@VVV\tau @VVV\\
A @>>> A @. 
\end{CD}
$$
all hold ($\alpha$ is the associator of $\otimes$). Evidently, if $\cal K$ is the 2-category of categories and $A$ is a monoidal category, an endo-cell with strength is an [endofunctor equipped with a monoidal strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_monad).

Has anyone studied this notion?